# If $|a^{2}|=|b^{2}|$ then $|a|=|b|?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

If $|a^{2}|=|b^{2}|$ (for non identity elements $a$ and $b$ of a group $G$ and $|a|$ denotes the order of the element $a$) prove or disprove that $|a|=|b|.$

I tried as follows

Clearly infinite order case is trivial. Let is discuss finite order case
$$|a^{2}|=|b^{2}|$$
$\Rightarrow$$$\frac{|a|}{(2,|a|)}=\frac{|b|}{(2,|b|)}  $$ where $(2,|a|)$  is the $\gcd$. Now I am stuck. How proceed further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know, we can't read your mind. I guess $a,b$ are elements of some group and $|x|$ is the order of $x$, i.e. the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $x^n$ is the unit of the group...? It's not at all clear from your question.

Comment: yes i m going to edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you have already reduced this to a question about elementary number theory: are there two numbers $m,n > 1$ such that $m \ne n$ but $m/(2,m) = n/(2,n)$?

Comment: yes its same question ..one can think in number theory

Comment: @neela Have you looked for any solutions??  There is one in single digits... It's not hard to find.  Why don't you explain where you are stuck?

Comment: trying the same..

Comment: if $|<a>|=6$ then $a^{2}$ and $a^{4}$ will work...am i right?

Comment: @neela Assuming you mean $|a^2|=|a^4|$ but $|a| \ne |a^2|$, then yes.  But typically one would express a counterexample by specifying the values of $a$ and $b$ rather than $a^2$ and $b^2$ :).

Comment: Take $b=a^{2}$ and its order is 3 whereas order of a is 6.

Comment: @neela Good job :).  By the way, it is always possible to find a group containing elements of any order you desire.  It can be a finite group if you prescribe finitely many elements of finite order; there are also infinite groups containing infinitely many elements of each possible order $>1$.  So once you have figured out the orders of $a$ and $b$, a counterexample is not far away.

Comment: thanks a lot for such a good help...

Answer (score 2):

(EDIT along *Erick Wong*'s comment - I overlooked the (somewhat irrelevant) condition that the elements should not be the identity).

Consider the cyclic group of order $6$. Let $a$ be a generator and $b=a^2$. Then $a^2=b$ and $b^2$ have order $3$, but $a$ has order $6$.

Comment: One of those two will be the identity :).

Comment: yes the question is about non trivial elements..

Comment: @neela You can use almost the same example with non-identity elements.  What if $|a|=3$ and $|b|=6$?

Comment: i am also searching the counterexample ...if possible give the counterexample..

Comment: @neela Can you not find a group where there are elements of order $3$ and $6$?